# Baseline correction on epoched EEG data

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, baseline

I am supposed to baseline-correct some EEG data in Matlab that I have already epoched. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to subtract the mean of the first samples of every channel from the whole length of the channel. Typically the baseline window is 100ms or more before the event.